# Can I mount an LED light bar to a truss web?

Tags: electrical, lighting, truss

I have 4 foot long LED light bars that i would like to  mount in my crawl space. I’ve removed the sagging underfloor insulation and am doing wall insulation instead, so the truss bays are empty. Trusses are 14” deep.

Can I mount these lights to the web portion of the truss? Essentially, somewhere between the top and bottom chords. Lights would run parallel on the truss, and not span multiple trusses.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. They will not impart enough force to harm the truss webs. Cables, duct work, plumbing, and other things are routinely attached to truss webs.